# Programmatically check for scale information in a PDF document?

Tags: pdf

The main topic I am interested in is whether it is possible to store and extract well-structured *scale information* from a PDF document.

[ For example, most engineering or architectural drawings printed to a PDF would be scaled down, say 1/8 in. : 1 ft. So if actually printed to paper you could measure a part of the drawing in inches and then infer the actual real-world size in feet. ]

Is there any way to *programmatically* look for that scale information in the PDF format? e.g., from the example above, to extract the 1/8" : 1' ratio from the PDF.

I thought this was not even possible until I came across this statement in the Adobe document *[Grids, guides, and measurements in PDFs](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/grids-guides-measurements-pdfs.html)*:

> **Use Scales And Units From Document (When Present)**
>
> When enabled, measurements based on the units generated from the
> original document, if present, are used. Deselect this option to
> specify the units of measurements manually.

([Alternative document](https://helpx.adobe.com/content/dam/help/en/pdf/acrobat_reference.pdf) with same text, p. 92)

However I can find no other references that explain how this feature works. I checked in the [PDF specifications](http://%C2%A0https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/pdf_reference_archives/PDFReference.pdf) (maybe too old of a version?) and it did not mention anything. But its hard to know what to search for and I'm not very familiar with PDF internals so I may simply have missed it.

A related detail is what level of the PDF this information would be stored at (if it exists at all) - I would guess per-page?

---

To be clear, I am absolutely not looking to scrape text from the rendered PDF. Instead, I want to find out if there is any **metadata** that would encode this information. The PDFs I have to deal with would have widely varying origins & contents.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the actual PDF specification (i.e. ISO 32000, part 1 or 2), you'll find a section on measurement properties.

E.g. in ISO 32000-1:

> #### 12.9 Measurement Properties
>
> PDF documents, such as those created by CAD software, may contain graphics that are intended to represent real-world objects. Users of such documents often require information about the scale and units of measurement of the corresponding real-world objects and their relationship to units in PDF user space.
>
> ...
>
> Beginning with PDF 1.6, such information may be stored in a *measure dictionary* (see Table 261). Measure dictionaries provide information about measurement units associated with a rectangular area of the document known as a *viewport*.
>
> A viewport *(PDF 1.6)* is a rectangular region of a page. The optional **VP** entry in a page dictionary (see Table 30) shall specify an array of viewport dictionaries, whose entries shall be as shown in Table 260. Viewports allow different measurement scales (specified by the **Measure** entry) to be used in different areas of a page, if necessary.

etc. etc.

Thus, yes, you can *programmatically look for that scale information in the PDF format*. Beware, though, these properties are optional, so you'll find them only if the PDF producer was nice enough to provide them.